# python- with an undetermined tuple (str), how to find if a letter is in each one of the strings

Tags: python

So basically, the user is allowed to input any amount of strings that they want to when they call the function, as long as the it's a string and the strings are separated by commas and have quotation marks around them. For example:

```
  func("str1", "str2", "str3")
```

I want to look at each one of these strings that they put in and see if it contains a specific character, like the letter 'a' for example. If they all contain the letter, I want to return true, if they don't, I want to return false. How can I look at each of the strings they put in (because there is no specified amount) and check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func(*args):
    return all('a' in str(x) for x in args)
```

Comment: nice and simple :P (+1 from me)

Comment: Why does it need the `str` around x?

Comment: I guess it catches if one of the parameters is not a string.

Comment: You could omit **kwargs

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(*args):
    if not all([isinstance(x,basestring) for x in args]):return False
    return reduce(lambda x,y:set(x).intersection(y),args)
```

might give you the info you want

```
"a" in   func("str1", "str2", "str3") == False
"s" in   func("str1", "str2", "str3")  == True
```